# How do I Uninstall HubSpot

Tags: email

How do I uninstall Hubspot on a Mac. I do not use it and everytime I open up email I am asked to sign in.
I have no idea what your quality standards are - all I want to do is get rid of the program

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're referring to is called Sidekick, Hubspot's email plugin.

1. Download the uninstaller: http://goo.gl/R6FSmJ
2. Unzip the file, and run the command.  This will remove all Sidekick files on your computer.

If you receive an error, go to your System Preferences and click on Security and Privacy. Then select "Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere". You can then change this back once the installer is done running.

Comment: For anyone who needs help with that just open terminal and run: `rm -rf ~/Library/Mail/Bundles/SmokeSignals.mailbundle` then `rm -rf ~/Library/Mail/Bundles/Sidekick.mailbundle`. That's what's in the uninstaller script.